# Can I invoke local cmdlet on remote machine with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've been tasked with retrieving information about all virtual machines running on a remote server. I'm using PowerShell 5 on my local machine but the remote server only has Powershell 2. My local machine has cmdlet Get-VM while the remote server does not.

This is what I tried doing:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-VM} -ComputerName Remote_Server
```

But I got this error:

```
The term 'Get-VM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-VM:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : CP-IN-VS01
```

What is the best way to get a list of the virtual machines given that the remote server does not have this cmdlet?

Comment: Does    `get-vm -computername remote_server` not work (from local machine)

Comment: It does not. I get this error: `Get-VM : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. A DMTF resource URI was used to access a non-DMTF class. Try again using a non-DMTF 
resource URI.`

Comment: Have you tried via WMI with something like this? $VSMgtSvc=Get-WmiObject -ComputerName 'CP-IN-VS01' -NameSpace "root\
virtualization" -Class "MsVM_virtualSystemManagementService"

Comment: I have not, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: You have to enable remote execution on the remote machine for any remote commands to work. In the configuration you can allow only your local machine to execute commands. PowerShell default turns this off due to security concerns.

Comment: @KolobCanyon I have enabled remote execution already. The issue is that I have a cmdlet on my local computer that is not on the remote computer